# problems with keypress events in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, angularjs, keypress

I'm new to Angular, help will be much appreciated. I'm making an app which has different areas, let's call it pages (even though it's truly a 1 page app) for which I naturally use different views, and I have a common layout with the body, styles and scripts etc.

I'm running into a problem in which I want to listen to keyboard events in only one of the pages of the app which is meant to be interactive while the others are administrative. I can bind keyboard events to inputs or to the document or body. Input is not suitable and  my document and body are global and I don't want to listen for every single keypress in my app.

What am I supposed to do to solve this problem in Angular?

My code is here: https://github.com/mgenev/geminiFc/blob/master/public/js/controllers/practice.js

I cheated with jQuery and bound the event to the body in the controller for the particular page, but Angular wasn't reacting like an event happened.

```
$('body').keydown(function(e) {
            $scope.changeIndex(e);
});
```

Then I read I have to use $scope.$apply(); which I did in the bottom of the changeIndex function which the event fires.

This actually worked, but when I call the changeIndex through a click event which is the alternative way of controlling my UI

```
   <div class="practice-controls-bottom">
        <i ng-click="changeIndex('down');" class="icon-thumbs-down icon-4x thumbs-down"></i>
        <i ng-click="changeIndex('up');" class="icon-thumbs-up icon-4x thumbs-up pull-right"></i>
    </div>
```

Angular gives me an error:

```
Error: $apply already in progress
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at g (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:85:37)
    at Object.e.$apply (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.min.js:89:129)
    at Object.$scope.changeIndex (http://localhost:3000/js/controllers/practice.js:173:20)
```

Looking forward to some advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try either one of the following solutions

Call the $scope.$apply in the keydown handler instead of changeindex method

```
$('body').keydown(function (e) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.changeIndex(e);
    })
});
```

or check whether the code is running within a apply/digest cycle before calling $apply in  `changeIndex` again like

```
if(!$scope.$$phase){
    $scope.$apply()
}
```

Comment: Your last code block were you check if a digest cycle is running works like a charm. Small typo though: `$scope.$apply()`

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a look at the ng-keypress, ng-keyup, ng-keydown directives? That way, you could only set the directive on the element inside the view you have to listen to keypresses.

Doc: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngKeypress

**EDIT:** Add `tabindex="0"` to enable key events on any element.

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/whXgmQU1pKjuRqvokC2Z

**html**

```
<div ng-keypress="changeIndex($event)" tabindex="0">Something</div>
```

**js**

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', [function($scope) {
    $scope.changeIndex = function($event) {
        // $event.keyCode...
    }
}]);
```

There is also a directive in Angular-UI http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/ that let you associate key combinaisons with functions.

```
<div ui-keypress="{13:'changeIndex($event)'}"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, i did try this, but i didn't have any luck binding keypress to divs, i even tried to force a focus on it to see if it works, but no luck

Comment: The reason is that you must add `tabindex="0"` to the div in order to enable key events! It works for any element.

Comment: i will try that, will be superb if it works, thanks!

Comment: You can have a look at the demo and see it working hopefully!

Comment: i did check the demo and it worked quite well, but for me it still didn't strangely, i wonder if it's because your controller is hooked to the body and mine isn't?

Comment: I had a look into your practice.js controller and I did not see any changeIndex function. Be sure that what you put in ng-keypress is in the current scope and it should work well!

Comment: ah sorry, i changed it since then, my html is here: https://github.com/mgenev/geminiFc/blob/master/public/views/stacks/practice.html

Comment: For example, to listen to keypresses on `<section  data-ng-controller="PracticeController" data-ng-init="loadCards();" ng-keypress="changeIndex($event)">`. You need to make sure that changeIndex($event) is a function in your PracticeController $scope, which I cannot find.

Comment: yes, sorry, it was this way, but i changed it, now the function is called keyHandler

Comment: i've successfully made ng-keypress work with inputs and the body tag, but not with a div, i added the tab index and the UI responds to that when I click the div, but still no keypress event fires.

Comment: I edited the plunker to test some more with nested elements/keypress and unfortunately i cannot understand why it doesnt work on your side.  Did you remove the jquery event when testing? http://plnkr.co/edit/whXgmQU1pKjuRqvokC2Z?p=preview

Comment: likewise, i tried nesting your plunkr and it worked, i'm not sure myself, i'll bang my head against the wall after work and tell you what i come up with

Comment: wow, so I kept trying and trying and got no results with ng-keypress until I copied the script tag with the angular lib from your plunker and replaced my version of angular with that and it started working. thank you for your help!

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help you.